# Mysql limit records depending on size output

Tags: mysql, size, limit

I'm wondering if it is possible to limit the number of records as output of a query depending on the size (kb) of the output. In particular, in my database there is a table that could contain a long description. Using for example LIMIT 0,15, fifteen records could have a huge description or a simple one, but I would like to receive a fixed amount of data (incrementing or reducing the number of records automatically) 
Is there any other instruction to limit the output?

Another option is getting the number of chars, summing them, set a limit and perform a join with the original query. But I think it is not the best way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by keeping track of the length in a variable and then stopping when some threshhold is exceeded:

```
select descr
from (select descr, @size := @size + length(descr) as size
      from table t cross join
           (select @size := 0) const
     ) t
where size <= 100000;
```

Your definition of the length for each record may be more sophisticated, but this should give you the idea.

Comment: If you want to thank Gordon, how about voting up and accepting?

Comment: @user3194723 . . . Is there a reason that you unaccepted the answer?